# Why do I get the following warning: Illegal string offset 'grade_id' and 'grade_name'?

Tags: php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_grade WHERE grade_id = '".$_POST["grade_id"]."'";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

if($statement->execute()){
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row){
        $output['grade_id'] = $row['grade_id'];
        $output['grade_name'] = $row['grade_name'];
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Day!

please try to declare array before foreach statement.

```
$output = array();
foreach($result as $row){
   $output['grade_id'] = $row['grade_id'];
   $output['grade_name'] = $row['grade_name'];
}
```

Thank you.